# Android - In App Purchase Testing - Do I Need 2 Phones?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

Here is the Android official site about In App Purchase testing:

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing#test-purchases-sandbox

Does this mean I have to buy 2 separate Android phones if I want to test my own In app purchases myself? Is it possible for me to personally do it with just one phone.

I am buying an Android phone today. So if I need to do anything special with that phone in setting it up, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I get from description you can setup new test account and use it for testing purposes. To be sure that app will be installed from your test account you can remove your personal account from the device. As for me, I just check the account in Google Play before making purchase.
So you just need to:

1. Setup test account in the Developer Console.
2. Add test account to your device
3. In Google Play choose your test account
4. Make a test purchase

There is no need in second separate device